# Yii CSqlDataProvider confusion

Tags: yii

I am having some trouble understanding [CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider) and how it works.

When I am using [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider), the results can be accessed as follows:

```
$data->userProfile['first_name'];
```

However, when I use CSqlDataProvider, I understand that the results are returned as an array not an object.  However, the structure of the array is flat.  In other words, I am seeing the following array:

```
$data['first_name']
```

instead of

```
$data['userProfile']['first_name']
```

But the problem here is what if I have another joined table (let's call it 'author') in my sql code that also contains a first_name field?  With CActiveDataProvider, the two fields are disambiguated, so I can do the following to access the two fields:

```
$data->userProfile['first_name'];
$data->author['first_name'];
```

But with CSqlDataProvider, there doesn't seem to be anyway I can access the data as follows:

```
$data['userProfile']['first_name'];
$data['author']['first_name'];
```

So, outside of assigning a unique name to those fields directly inside my SQL, by doing something like this:

```
select author.first_name as author_first_name, userProfile.first_name as user_first_name
```

And then referring to them like this:

$data['author_first_name'];
$data['user_first_name']

is there anyway to get CSqlDataProvider to automatically structure the arrays so they are nested in the same way that CActiveDataProvider objects are?  So that I can call them by using $data['userProfile']['first_name']

Or is there another class I should be using to obtain these kinds of nested arrays?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no Yii DB methods break out JOIN query results in to 2D arrays like you are looking for. I think you will need to - as you suggest - alias the column names in your select statement.

MySql returns a single row of data when you JOIN tables in a query, and CSqlDataProvider returns exactly what MySql does: single tabular array representation indexed/keyed by the column names, just like your query returns.

If you want to break apart your results into a multi-dimensional array I would either alias the columns, or use a regular [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) (which you can still pass complex queries and joins in via [CDbCritiera](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider#criteria-detail)).